# Creating a navigationnode of type Link from csom

Tags: 2013, office-365, client-object-model

I have a publishing enabled web that I want to add a link to, not a heading.

```
var node = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Add(new NavigationNodeCreationInformation { Title = "Dokument", Url = web.Url + "/Shared Documents" });
```

This is the only way to create a new node in the quicklaunch (that I know of). None of the other props help.

And there is no `node.properties["NodeType"]` in CSOM that we can set to `Heading` and such, as there is in the on-prem library.

Now the node get's created fine, but it's always of type Heading. I need it to be a normal link.

I'm starting to feel like this is just one of those things that is not in the CSOM API yet. True or false?

Answer (score 1):

It is (still) not implemented in csom.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.navigationnode_members.aspx there is no properties member or any other way to set type.

BTW also no way to set audience.

Only way to this programatically right now is send http request to the AreaNavigationSettings.aspx and set node variable there. And that is kinda crazy.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer with some proof of reference to Microsoft's msdn articles. It will simply add more value to your answer to be accepted.